# Scrapy adds %0A to URLs, causing them to fail

Tags: python, encoding, scrapy, http-status-code-404, python-requests

I'm almost at my wits end with this one. Basically I have a url that seems to be somehow magical. Specifically it's this:

> https://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031

When I hit it with `requests`, everything works fine:

```
import requests
test = requests.get("https://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031")
<Response [200]>
```

However, when I use `scrapy`, the following line pops out:

```
Crawled (404) <GET https://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031%0A>
```

I even tried updating my User-Agent string to no avail. Part of me is concerned that the URL-encoding `%0A` is responsible, but that seems like it would be rather strange, and I can't find any documentation on how to fix it.

For reference, this is how I'm sending the request, though I'm not sure this will add much information:

```
for url in review_urls:
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_review_urls)
```

It's important to note that this is the exception rather than the rule. Most URLs work unhindered, but these edge cases are not uncommon.

Comment: could you please post the contents of review_urls ?

Comment: @Jithin I assume you mean `get_review_urls`? It never makes it to the callback. I figured out what was happening. I'm writing up the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think thats the problem with the scrapy, I suspect there is a problem with your `review_urls`,

plese find this demo from the `scrapy-shell`, somehow your url has ended with a newline feed, (docs [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)) during the `url-encoding` that `\n` is converted to `%0A`. Seems like your are accidently added a newline character at the end of the url or the extracted url contains an extra new line feed.

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031'
2015-08-02 05:48:56 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2015-08-02 05:48:56 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-08-02 05:48:56 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0}
2015-08-02 05:48:56 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-08-02 05:48:56 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-08-02 05:48:56 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-08-02 05:48:56 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-08-02 05:48:56 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-08-02 05:48:56 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-08-02 05:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031> from <GET https://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031>
2015-08-02 05:48:59 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7fe36d76fbd0>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7fe365b91c50>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x7fe36420d110>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
2015-08-02 05:48:59 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger
2015-08-02 05:48:59 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger

In [1]: url = 'https://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031\n'

In [2]: fetch(url)
2015-08-02 05:49:24 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031%0A> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7fe36d76fbd0>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031%0A>
[s]   response   <404 https://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031%0A>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7fe365b91c50>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x7fe36420d110>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
```

perform a `strip()` on the urls before you make a request and will give you the desired results as follows,

```
In [3]: fetch(url.strip())
2015-08-02 05:53:01 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031> from <GET https://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031>
2015-08-02 05:53:03 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7fe36d76fbd0>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.amazon.de/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=3010075031>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7fe365b91c50>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x7fe36420d110>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
```

Comment: This was totally what I was going to write up! I'm submitting a patch to `scrapy` about this.

Comment: Clap clap ... finally I know where I made mistake too